# RoR recall function without refreshing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter

When I generate my view I retrieve a list of tweets from twitter with something like that :

```
# Print tweets from list_id
<% @twitter_client.list_timeline(list_id).each do |tweet| %>
  <%= tweet.text %>
  <br />
<% end %>
```

**This result is static**, you will only get the last 20 tweets of this list. But I want it to be automatically refreshed every minutes for example. How is it possible to recall it without refreshing the entire page ?

I thought about Ajax but it's a view generated by rails so how can Ajax recall only this specific function ?

Thanks for your advices

Comment: Yes, if you need to do some server-side computing (like retrieving some tweets) without reloading the client's page, you need AJAX. You can make an AJAX call to your server every minute (thanks to javascript's `setTimeout`), your server receive the AJAX call and retrieves the new tweets, then send back the answer to the client's page, which will need Javascript to interpret the server's answer and put the new tweets in the page.

Answer (score 2):

Ajax typically makes a request and then updates a **part** of the page with the results.  It can make a request to your rails app which can in turn make a request to twitter, get some data back, generate a chunk of html and then send it back as part of the response to the ajax query.

So, it's like this

Browser javascript

- make ajax request to eg /twitter_clients/123 which awaits response

Rails Server:

- gets request for "/twitter_clients/123" which gets routes to eg twitter_clients#show
- twitter_clients#show action loads the necessary data to make a twitter api call, makes it, and then gets some data back.
- in the format.js handler for the show action, replace a div eg with id "twitter_feed" with a partial, "twitter_clients/feed".

(Effectively, the controller uses the data to build a chunk of html using that partial, then sends it back to the ajax request (which is patiently waiting for it), telling the request to "take this chunk of text and use it to replace the contents of the div with id "twitter_feed".)

Back in the browser:

- ajax response comes back, the javascript replaces the #twitter_feed div with the contents of the response.

Comment: Thanks @Max I will go this way, this doesn't seems hard to implement as well !

Comment: To save time and maximize the performances usages, you can use JSON instead of rendering HTML content. Then, on the client-side, the Javascript will handle this JSON and display the tweets (creating divs, spans, etc). Also, if the first request to `/twitter_clients/123` takes some time to compute because of the tweets retrieving process, you can simply render an empty view (without tweet) and then in your view trigger an AJAX call to retrieve the first tweets. It is like asynchronous loading.

Comment: Yes, this is better from a performance point of view, but it requires the javascript to know about how the twitter data is arranged on the page, ie to know how the view template is structured.  This may be inconvenient and is certainly more prone to breaking.  On the other hand, you can use existing twitter feed plugins which come with their own markup and styling and which probably are suitable to your needs.  Then you can completely remove Rails from the equation.